# resample multiple columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample daily stock data into monthly stock data.

```
data = yf.download(['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'FB'], '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')['Close']

for column in data:
    data[column].resample('M').last()
    print(data[column])

print(data)
```

My data:

```
                  AAPL          FB        TSLA
Date                                          
2018-01-02  172.259995  181.419998  320.529999
2018-01-03  172.229996  184.669998  317.250000
2018-01-04  173.029999  184.330002  314.619995
2018-01-05  175.000000  186.850006  316.579987
2018-01-08  174.350006  188.279999  336.410001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't resample individual columns and assign it to the same DataFrame variable. You can just apply the resample call to the entire DataFrame:

```
data = yf.download(['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'FB'], '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')['Close']

data_resampled = data.resample('M').last()

print(data)
```

Comment: can you resample only few columns of dataframe?

Comment: It is possible to selectively resample dataframe columns using .agg():    df = df.resample().agg({'col':'method', ...})